# Package visibility android Sdk 30

Tags: android, android-permissions, google-play-console, android-11

I recently targeted Android sdk 30 and I added the following snippet in my code

```
   <permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
```

Seems is working in many devices,and i can get package info like Installed apps , however in some devices like samsung or one plus one (OnePlus7Pro_EE) does not work, I'm not sure how to solve this issue. if I use the full permissions will work

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
```

however doing this will means I need to apply for exhausting review and Permissions Declaration, which might be rejected. seems is working in most of the devices, but in few devices it does not work. what I want to achieve is get information about the installed apps and icon an example:

```
packageManager.getApplicationIcon(packageName)
```

doing this throw `PackageManager$NameNotFoundException`

Comment: "however in some devices like samsung or one plus one (OnePlus7Pro_EE) does not work" -- your [mcve] should be showing what you are doing that involves this `<queries>` element and what the symptoms are that you are getting on those devices. Also, you really need to get rid of that `<permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />` element. That permission is defined by the framework, not an app.

Comment: I edited my question, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Only these lines in the manifest are enough to get app info such as name and icon

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Comment: Unfortunately as I wrote on my post, some in some devices does not work, and I can't debug because is like 1% of the users and is hard to figure out why